# Rails models: message and attachment dependence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I have a chat message model and a chat message attachment model.  When a user requests a chat message with an attachment: first the chat message itself is created, then the attachment is created, then the association between the two is created.

The issue is that I would like the chat message to require a body, but only if there is no attachment.  If there is an attachment, I would like the message to not require a body.

How can I pre-emptively set (or not-set) this requirement, using validations, when creating the message, knowing that an attachment will/will-not be created before-hand?

Comment: Why don't you create the records at the same time? Please show your current code (form view, controller method, models).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how does your controller look like, however if this is done in one request (which normally is), you can simply add a custom validator. For example:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :attachment

  validate do
    if attachment.nil?
      errors.add(:body, 'must be present') if body.blank?
    end
  end
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
end
```

If you have validations on the `Attachment` model, you can first check it by `attachment.valid?`.